# optimization problem entrance

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

[image]

Can anybody give me a constructive approach of how to tackle this kind of problems?

Comment: Consider the graph of the function $f(x)=x(1-x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a derivative to find a stationary point: $(x(1-x))' = 1-2x=0$. Thus, at $x^*=0.5$ the function has the maximum $0.25$. It is maximum since the second derivative is negative. For any $0 \lt \beta \lt 0.5,$ we'll have $x^* = \beta$.